# Multiple combination cross reference

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I have a very poorly designed system that I have inherited and am trying to clean up.  I have four different systems with client names.  None of them have a common ClientID or ClientCode or anything good like that.  In a few systems they're the same, but in most they have just basic differences, some with dashes or parentheses, abbreviations, acronyms, etc.  I have created cross reference tables in the past where could map "Client A" to "ClntA", no problem.  My problem comes when I'm trying to create a cross reference for more than two systems.

I could create a table that has columns for SystemA, SystemB, SystemC, and SystemD, but there would obviously be overlap.  For instance, I could have:

> 1    ClientA      ClientA       Client A          Clnt A
>   2    ClientA      ClientA       Customer A        Clnt A

In that case SystemA, SystemB, and SystemD are all the same, so If I query a combination to look up SystemA to SystemB mapping, I get two results.  I'm not sure that a distinct is the best idea.  I have thought about creating views like

> CREATE VIEW SysA_SysB_Xref AS
>      SELECT DISTINCT SystemA, SystemB FROM myTable

But I'm not sure that helps either.

Any help on basic design for this?

Thanks!

Comment: I have also tried things like SOUNDEX and fuzzy matching algorithms, which help in a few cases, but don't cover everything I need.

Answer (score 1):

You need brand new system-wide `Clients` table with it's own Id. Start with copy of SystemA names for example assigning new ids. And now have N separate mapping tables for every SystemA , ... adding new clients as needed to brand new Id.